# click anywhere in Card on a Antd radio button wrapped inside a Card to change border and background on select

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, antd

I have a antd radio button that I wrapped it around a card to make it more custom.  What I am trying to do is be able to click anywhere and make the radio button selectable as well as change the card border-color and background color when selected
Here is my code.

```
  <Card hoverable style={{ borderRadius: '10px', borderColor: 'lightgray'}} bordered>
    <Meta
      style={{float: 'left'}}
      avatar={<Avatar shape="square" src='/resources/images/document.png' />}
    />
    <Radio value="Subscription Docs">Subscription Docs</Radio>
  </Card>
```

any ideas on the best approach?

Comment: Ideally, you would have a state attached to its value if it's selected or not and then based on that pass that in the style of the parent.

Answer (score 0):

Check the following code using state to change the css class

Demo.js

```js
import React, { useState } from 'react';
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
import 'antd/dist/antd.css';
import './index.css';
import { Card, Radio, Avatar } from 'antd';

const Demo = () => {
  const { Meta } = Card;

  const [cardselected, setCardselected] = useState(false);

  const onChange = (e) => {
    console.log(e.target.checked);
    if (e.target.checked) {
      setCardselected(true);
    } else {
      setCardselected(false);
    }
  };

  return (
    <Card
      hoverable
      className={cardselected ? 'card-selected' : 'card-notselected'}
      bordered
    >
      <Meta
        style={{ float: 'left' }}
        avatar={<Avatar shape="square" src="/resources/images/document.png" />}
      />
      <Radio value={cardselected} onChange={onChange}>
        Subscription Docs
      </Radio>
    </Card>
  );
};
```

index.css

```css
.card-notselected {
  border-radius: 10px;
  border-color: lightgray;
}

.card-selected {
  border-radius: 10px;
  background-color: #575ae9;
  border-color: #2412c7;
}
```

When radio button is not selected

[image: Screenshot]

When radio button is selected

[image: Screenshot]